# Call to an API to retrieve JSON data and store it in the database

Tags: php, jquery, database, json, api

What do I need to do in order to make a call to an API, retrieve some data in JSON format and then store that data into a database. I know the specifics of this process, but the thing is I need this to be done at an interval of 5 minutes and without placing burden on the loading time of the website. So, I don't know the concept of how this is done because it obviously can't be done when the page is loaded, hence it has to be done by the server, but how ?

Any useful reading material regarding this topic would also come in handy. Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to write a separate script to do this work, and call that script from a cron job (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), assuming you're on a Unix/Linux system, or from the Windows Task Scheduler, if you're on Windows.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run the process on a cron. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: I didn't know that you could apply cron jobs to a situation like this, will give it a look. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Cron jobs can be applied to just about anything you can shake a script at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the new web workers method in HTML 5.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

You tagged this as a jquery question so I assume you already know how to make an ajax call. If you know how to make an ajax call Im sure you can figure out how to use setInterval to make this repeat every x number of seconds. But just in case take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

This is assuming you want to do this on the page itself, otherwise as others have commented just set up a cron job.

Comment: I already have this "on the page setup" you are referring to but thanks to your kind answers I now know that I need a cron job. Anyways thanks for the info, the web workers will definitely come in handy.

Comment: No problem, you said you needed a non-block way to do this and web workers is the new way to do it.